# Plot the area between two curves

Tags: charts, gnuplot

I have a function with a parameter z similar to the above one:

```
y = sin(x+z)
```

How can I plot the values of *y* as a function of *x* and all the possible values of *z* in the [0.1, +0.1]?

I want to graphic the area defined by those limits. So everything bounded by sin(x-0.1) and sin(x+0.1) would be shaded, everything outside would be white space.

I'm trying to accomplish this with *gnuplot*, but with any software would probably be fine.

Comment: Maybe something like `plot '+' using ($1):(sin($1+.1)):(sin($1-.1))  w filledcurves`

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use the pseudofile `+` and plot with the filledcurves option:

```
set termoption enhanced
set style fill transparent solid 0.70 noborder
set key off
set sample 1000
set xlabel "{/*1.2x}" 
set ylabel "{/*1.2f(x)}"
plot [0:2*pi] '+' using ($1):(sin($1+.1)):(sin($1-.1))  w filledcurves
```

[image]

Comment: That's the case {sin(x-0.1) < y < sin(x+0.1)} U {sin(x-0.1) > y > sin(x+0.1)}. It's not sure what the OP wanted anyway.

Comment: After 5-6 year I'm not sure that even the OP know it `:D` I try to take an hint when the OP states _"So everything bounded by sin(x-0.1) and sin(x+0.1) would be shaded, everything outside would be whitespace"_

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `filledcurves`.

To plot the set {sin(x-0.1) < y < sin(x+0.1)}, use:

```
unset key
set sample 1000
plot sin(x+0.1) w filledcurves y=-1 lw 0
replot sin(x-0.1) w filledcurves y=-1 lc rgbcolor "white" lw 0
```